# Are Aura Components, Lightning Web Components and Visualforce pages based on MVC architecture paradigm?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, architecture

This may sound at first sight as a question which has been answered many times, but it has always been related to a specific thing and I've heard people have different opinions on this topic. Also, I have not found any official part of documentation I could use to base my reasoning on directly.

- Are Aura Components, Lightning Web Components and Visualforce pages based on MVC (Model-View-Controller) architecture paradigm?
- Would it be far-fetched to say that given the fact that we use JavaScript controller and Apex controller, the architecture paradigm can be called MVCC (Model-View-Controller-Controller)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most frameworks reasonably can be described as MVC. It's not a particularly helpful distinction. With MVC, there are three or more components that are split into three roles, Model-View-Controller. More than one component can be in one role, and more than one role can be filled by one component. Don't use MVCC, though, as that means multiversion concurrency control, a feature of databases that can provide different versions of the database at different points in time per client in a consistent manner. I wouldn't say the various frameworks were designed specifically by MVC paradigms, just that it is a fairly obvious design pattern.